# Why do I need to write (doc str) but (meta #'str)?

Tags: syntax, clojure, macros

Why `(doc str)` but `(meta #'str)`?

In the latter one, why is the `#'` necessary, which isn't in the first one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`doc` is a macro which internally applies `#'` i.e `var` to the passed name, hence you don't need to pass the var itself to it. `meta` is a function and hence it needs the var itself to be passed otherwise the value of the var will get passed to it if you use just the name of the var (as done in `doc`)

Comment: I wanted to better understand your answer, so I did some experimentation in the REPL, captured here: https://gist.github.com/3422860

Answer (score 0):

`#'` is the reader macro, #'str expands to (var str), return the Var object, see doc:

```
user> (doc meta)
-------------------------
clojure.core/meta
([obj])
  Returns the metadata of obj, returns nil if there is no metadata.
```